# How to use a custom mosquitto.conf file in a docker container in windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, mosquitto, broker

I'm having a tough time trying to set a custom .conf file in mosquitto image which is running in docker. The problem is I'm not being able to set the volumes properly in windows, I did the same process in linux Fedora at work and mosquitto broker worked perfectly. I ran over a lot of websites and videos on youtube and of course mosquitto documentation but none of them helped me out.

I've been using docker-compose.yml to set up the volume

```
version: "3"

networks:
   appnetwork:
     ipam:
     driver: default
     config:
       - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24

services:
   app:
   build: .
   command: npm start
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
   volumes:
     - .:/usr/app

mosquitto:
  image: eclipse-mosquitto
  container_name: mosquitto
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./mosquitto/conf:/mosquitto/conf
    - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
    - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
  ports:
    - 1883:1883
    - 9001:9001

networks:
  appnetwork:
    ipv4_address: 172.20.0.7
```

That's my files' tree

[image]

Then,when I run `docker-compose up` the image runs fine but I'm getting the following log

```
mosquitto    | 1664313457: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting                                                                                                  
mosquitto    | 1664313457: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.                                                                               
mosquitto    | 1664313457: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be 
               possible from clients running on this machine.                               
mosquitto    | 1664313457: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow 
               remote access.                                                       
mosquitto    | 1664313457: For more details see 
                https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/                                                   
mosquitto    | 1664313457: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.                                                                                           
mosquitto    | 1664313457: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.                                                                                           
mosquitto    | 1664313457: Error: Address not available                                                                                                       
mosquitto    | 1664313457: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

As you can see, Even though I defined a static IP It didn't work because the Address is not available. So that's the problem I don't know how to solve it in windows, but my guess would be starting by setting the volume correctly. However, How coI do that?

Comment: Just something to try. Try mounting the `mosquitto.conf` file explicitly, not just the `conf` directory e.g. `/mosquitto/conf/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/conf/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: Thanks for replying to me @hardillb, I did as you said but It's not working yet I still getting the same log I even tried this approach http://iotdotnet.blogspot.com/2018/10/running-mosquitto-mqtt-in-container-on.html but It has not worked as well.